# How Can I Update an SQL database with a foreach loop?

Tags: php, sql, foreach

I have a photo gallery and want to update multiple captions at once via form input.  I've tried to research this but I think I'm in way over my head.  This is what I have so far but it's not working..

The data is saved in an SQL table called "gallery".  An example row might look like:

```
gallery_id(key) = some number
product_id      = 500
photo           = photo.jpg
caption         = 'look at this picture'
```

My form inputs are generated like this:

> $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM gallery WHERE product_id = 500");
>
> ```
>  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
>   $photo=$row['photo'];
>   $caption=$row['caption'];
>   echo '<img src="$photo"/>';
>   echo '<input name="cap['.$caption.']" id="cap['.$caption.']" value="'.$caption.'" />';
>   }
> ```

So once I submit the form I start to access my inputs like this but I hit a wall..

```
    if( isset($_POST['cap']) && is_array($_POST['cap']) ) {
       foreach($_POST['cap'] as $cap) {
        mysql_query("UPDATE gallery 
                     SET caption=$caption
                     WHERE ???????");
       }

    }
```

I don't know how to tell the database where to put these inputs and as far as I can tell you can't pass more than one variable in a foreach loop.

Comment: you neeed to pass the id of the original caption, too. So your statement would be along the lines of `UPDATE gallery SET caption = $caption WHERE gallery_id = $gallery_id` (i also hope you're showing the abbreviated code, otherwise you're opening yourself up to a several SQL injection).

Comment: Note that you should not be using the `mysql_*` functions any longer.  The whole range is [deprecated](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php).  It has not been updated or maintained in several years and exists only for backwards compatibility.  You should use `mysqli_*` or the `PDO` methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$_POST  is an array, if im not wrong (I can't test it now and im new in PHP) you can do

```
foreach ($_POST as $p) {
    $id=$p['id'];'
    $cap=$p['caption'];
mysql_query("UPDATE gallery 
                 SET caption=$cap
                 WHERE photoid=$id");

}
```

Comment: Thanks!  I wasn't even thinking about arrays. I'm going to study up on them more

Answer (score 0):

#### A few things to consider

Updating many rows is tricky. I see it's already answered so I'm not trying to give a *better answer*, but some non-trivials for those who find this thread by searching for `update sql many rows` or similar. It's a common scenario to update several rows, and I've seen many codes with the "one update a time" approach (described above) which **can be quite slow**. In many cases there are better ways. No one-fits-all solution here, so I tried to split up the possible techniques by what you have and where you're going:

- **Multiple rows, same data**
  If you want to set the same caption for many rows, `UPDATE ... WHERE ID IN (...)` - it's an edge case but it gives you a noticeable performance boost
- **Multiple rows, different data, at once**
  When updating several rows, consider using a CASE structure, as explained in this article:
  [sql update multiple rows with case in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16362799/sql-update-multiple-rows-with-case-in-php)
- **Transactions**
  If you're using InnoDB tables (which is quite likely), you may want to do the whole thing in one transaction. It's a lot faster.
- **Index updates**
  If you're updating many-many rows (like thousands), it can make sense to disable keys before and enable them afterwards. This way SQL can save a lot of index updates while it happens, and only do it for the final result.
- **Delete + reinsert**
  If you're updating many fields per record, and there are no triggers and other magic consequences of deleting your rows, it can be faster to delete them `WHERE ID IN(...)` and then do a multi-insert. Don't do this if you're only updating fixed-size integers like counters.

Then again:

- If your table has many concurrent reads & writes, and you're updating only a few (up to a hundred) rows, stick with the one-by-one approach. Especially if it's MyISAM.
- Try before you buy; these techniques all depend on data itself too. But it's worth to go some extra miles to find the best.