# sql update multiple rows with case in php

Tags: php, sql, database, case

I am trying to update 11 rows at a time - cricket team (11 players) posted from a form page before, and then I want to update the first table called with these players. (The table includes player, order and team.)

```
<?php
session_start();

// Edit this to connect to your database with your username and password
$db_name="a1467234_cricket"; // Database name 
$tbl_name="statistics"; // Table name 

// Connect to server and select databse.
$conn = mysql_connect("mysql17.000webhost.com","*******","*******") or die(mysql_error()); 
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");


$one = $_POST["one"];
$two = $_POST["two"];
$three = $_POST["three"];
$four = $_POST["four"];
$five = $_POST["five"];
$six = $_POST["six"];
$seven = $_POST["seven"];
$eight = $_POST["eight"];
$nine = $_POST["nine"];
$ten = $_POST["ten"];
$eleven = $_POST["eleven"];

$team = $_POST["team"];

$sql = "UPDATE first
   SET player = (CASE
       WHEN order = 1 ='$team' THEN '$one'
       WHEN order = 2 AND team ='$team' THEN '$two'
       WHEN order = 3 AND team ='$team' THEN '$three'
       WHEN order = 4 AND team ='$team' THEN '$four'
       WHEN order = 5 AND team ='$team' THEN '$five'
       WHEN order = 6 AND team ='$team' THEN '$six'
       WHEN order = 7 AND team ='$team' THEN '$seven'
       WHEN order = 8 AND team ='$team' THEN '$eight'
       WHEN order = 9 AND team ='$team' THEN '$nine'
       WHEN order = 10 AND team ='$team' THEN '$ten'
       WHEN order = 11 AND team ='$team' THEN '$eleven'
       ELSE player
     END
     WHERE order IN (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11))";

echo "Updated team selection";

mysql_close($conn);

?>
```

Does anyone know how to get the update script working please? No errors are displayed, and it just doesn't change the database.

Comment: You should probably remove the credentials...  Also, you have an end statement but no begin statement.  I'm not a SQL guru but I think its required.

Comment: Does the first WHEN statement have a syntax error?
WHEN order = 1 ='$team' THEN '$one'

Comment: oh sorry i just changed that no its the same as the others getting team is $team

Comment: check my answer.. this might be simple and clean for you :)

Answer (score 1):

You need a `mysql_query($sql);` to execute your query on the database

Answer (score 0):

Using for loop might be easier, neat and smarter way for your query. This might be little helpful for you:

```
<?php 
for($i=1;$i<$count;$i++) {
        $updatesql="update first set player ='".$_POST['player_'.$i]"' where team ='".$_POST['team_'.$i]"' ";
        mysql_query($updatesql);

}
?>
```

You might need slight modification with this one.

for eg. you need to post data in this way:

player_1, player_2 etc. and team in team_1, team_2 etc.

Answer (score 0):

bviously, you are missing a closing parenthesis ')' after the END.
By the way, the first case condition (order = 1 ='$team') doesn't seem to make any sense.

Anyway, the query below should work. Please note that the . . . would need to be populated in the same pattern as the first and second players.

```
 $sql = "
       UPDATE first a,
              (
                 SELECT 1 AS `order`, '{$one}' AS player, '{$team}' AS team
                 UNION ALL
                 SELECT 2 AS `order`, '{$two}' AS player, '{$team}' AS team
                 .
                 .
                 .
                 UNION ALL
                 SELECT 11 AS `order`, '{$eleven}' AS player, '{$team}' AS team
              ) b
          SET a.player = b.player
        WHERE a.`order` = b.`order`
          AND a.team = b.teamenter
      ";
```

Comment: yes sorry i accidently changed that when uploading its the same as the others and i put it after the where is that wrong ? thankyou